# How regex negation in java negate nested classes

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I have below program to replace the special charaters

```
      String a = "fgA9.^";
       String b ="";
       a = a.replaceAll("[^[a-zA-Z0-9]]", b);
       System.out.println(a);
```

This prints (.^) as a output but I expect the regex pattern negate the letters, digits and replace the special characters.

I can see my expected output by `a = a.replaceAll("[[^a-zA-Z0-9]]", b);`

what is the difference between two, in both cases I used negation?

Comment: You used a character class union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the nested character class, you created a [*union*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html):

> You can also use *unions* to create a single character class comprised of two or more separate character classes. To create a union, simply nest one class inside the other, such as `[0-4[6-8]]`. This particular union creates a single character class that matches the numbers `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `6`, `7`, and `8`.

The `"[^[a-zA-Z0-9]]"` regex matches alphanumeric chars as the pattern consists of `[^]` (the empty unioned part is ignored) and `[a-zA-Z0-9]` that matches ASCII letters and digits.

In the `[[^a-zA-Z0-9]]` pattern, you indicated a negated character class `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` that matches any char but an ASCII letter/digit, and unioned with an empty part, again, ignored.

The `[0-4[6-8]]` regex is fully semantically equivalent to `[0-46-8]`, and more practical union value can be observed in combining negated and positive character classes. E.g. `[^\p{L}[a-c]]+` will match one or more chars other than letters (`[^\p{L}]`) and the three lowercase `a`, `b` and `c` chars.